# Converting files into different formats using single reusable code

Tags: java

I am a beginner in API programming. I am trying to write a reusable function for converting files from one format to any other formats. I have an XML file and I would like to convert it into other file formats; for instance to `.json` or `.csv` files with the function.

I have created a java bean for that but I am not sure whether it helps me. I am kinda stuck how to start, any suggestions please, considering my XML file isall strings.

```
public class converter implements Serializable
{
    public String name;
    public String kind;
    public String url;
    public converter(){}
    public converter(String name, String kind, String url){
        getName(name);
        getKind(kind);
        getUrl(url);    
    }

    private void getUrl(String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.url = url;
    }
    private void getKind(String kind) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.kind = kind;
    }
    private void getName(String name) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.name = name;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like a [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) (or just search the web, tons of stuff on this one).

```
class Converter {
    ConversionAlgorithm algo;
    File file; // file to convert

    Converter(File file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    void setConversionAlgorithm(ConversionAlgorithm algo) {
        this.algo = algo;
    }

    File convert() {
        return algo.convert(file);
    }
}

interface ConversionAlgorithm {
    File convert(File toConvert);
}

class JSONConverter implements ConversionAlgorithm {

    @Override
    File convert(File toConvert) {
        // do the conversion from xml to json
    }
}

class CSVConverter implements ConversionAlgorithm {

    @Override
    File convert(File toConvert) {
        // do the conversion from xml to csv
    }
}
```

So you create the converter with the file you want to operate on. Then you set the conversion algorithm according to the file type you want to get and call convert. If you want to convert to something else then just switch the conversion algorithm.

Usage example:

```
class Example {

    static ConversionAlgorithm xmlTojson = new JSONConverter();
    static ConversionAlgorithm xmlTocsv = new CSVConverter();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File xml = ... // get it somehow
        Converter converter = new Converter(xml);
        converter.setConversionAlgorithm(xmlTojson);
        File json = converter.convert();
        converter.setConversionAlgorithm(xmlTocsv);
        File csv = converter.convert();
    }
}
```

You can also choose to change the file with a `setFile` method. there are really a lot of ways to go about it.

Comment: Thank you @Mark. I got an idea how to implement now but i didn´t understood 
`File convert() {
        return algo.convert(file);
    }` this logic in class converter, can you please explain me this.

Comment: moreover if i want to use the json object to convert the other file is it possible. i mean i am already having a  converted json file object and now i want to use this to call another method for converting into .csv file like
`csv File csv file = jsonFile.convertTocsv(); ` . Thanks

Comment: @many The converter class holds its conversion "strategy" (algorithm) in the form of a `ConversionAlgorithm` object. Each class implementing that interface is responsible for the logic as per the strategy pattern. That means that when the converter needs to convert it delegates the operation to its conversion algorithm. I hope this is clearer now.

Comment: You said you have an XML file you want to convert to other files. Now you want to convert other files to other files? Just write additional classes that implement `ConversionAlgorithm` and set them as the conversion strategy. i don't understand what `csv File csv file = jsonFile.convertTocsv();` is :(

Comment: thank you, i would just repeat again please correct me if i am wrong, suppose i am converting an xml file to json file from scratch, then i would create a new class with JSONConverter and implement the ConversionalAlgorithm  interface, and in JSONConverter class i would write the logic of converting from Xml to Json file format. This repeats( a new class should be created) for every new conversion type

Comment: @many I added a usage example. I don't understand why "create a new class with JSONConverter and implement the ConversionalAlgorithm interface," - that class already exists in my code. "in JSONConverter class i would write the logic of converting from Xml to Json file format." - yes where I put the commented line //do the conversion... "a new class should be created for every new conversion type " If you mean when you write the classes code then yes, but not when using it. All instances of a JSONConverter class are the same, so create 1 reference and hold it.